# React Native rounded image with a border

Tags: react-native

I want to create a rounded image with a border. If I add `borderColor: 'green', borderWidth:1`, border is visible only in top left part of the rounded image.

[image]

```
<TouchableHighlight
          style={[styles.profileImgContainer, { borderColor: 'green', borderWidth:1 }]}
        >
    <Image source={{ uri:"https://www.t-nation.com/system/publishing/articles/10005529/original/6-Reasons-You-Should-Never-Open-a-Gym.png" }} style={styles.profileImg} />
</TouchableHighlight>

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileImgContainer: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
  },
  profileImg: {
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`overflow: 'hidden'` for images container solves this issue.

Answer (score 52):

Use the following styling, it's work for me.

```
image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 150 / 2,
    overflow: "hidden",
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: "red"
  }
```

Answer (score 22):

**Worth to mention for Android...**

I had to specifically set `resizeMode="cover"` for the borderRadius to take effect.

```
<Image
  style={styles.image}
  source={source}
  resizeMode={"cover"} // <- needs to be "cover" for borderRadius to take effect on Android
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderColor: 'red,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 75
  },
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Border width adds up to the size of the component that you added to. This makes your image bigger than the size of your container component. To solve this issue you can add the border width to the component sizes.

**Example**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  profileImgContainer: {
    marginLeft: 8,
    height: 82,
    width: 82,
    borderRadius: 40,
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  profileImg: {
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    borderRadius: 40,
  },
});
```

Comment: It was just a small example to show what I described. I know you already added borderWidth.

Comment: Sorry, I know what you mean, but when I increased `borderWidth`, only visible part of border was bigger and bottom part was still without a border.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show the image with rounded corner and with resizeMode={'contain'} to show the full image then wrap the image inside a view and then give border radius to the view. it will work

```
 <View style={styles.carImageHolder}>
                    <Image
                      source={{
                        uri: each?.usercar_details?.car_model?.sized_photo,
                      }}
                      resizeMode={'contain'}
                      style={styles.carImage}
                    />
                  </View>
```

and the style part

```
  carImage: {
    width: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  },
  carImageHolder: {
    width: '28.3%',
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
    backgroundColor: '#d8d8d8',
    borderRadius: 25,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given here, are nice, but, from my experience, it's better to use percentages of your available screen height, as the width and height dimensions of image. This will help a lot with responsiveness. Do it like this

```
import RN from 'react-native';

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = RN.Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

Then apply the following as the dimensions styling, to get a nice, responsive rounded image.

```
style={[
    //... your other previous styles
    {
       resizeMode: 'cover',
       width: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.15,
       height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.15,
       borderRadius: (SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.15)/2,
     }
]}
```

The (*0.15 i.e 15% of screen height) is just my choice of sample dimensions, you can use higher or lower, depending on how big you want your image to be.