# How to add a border around React Color's CirclePicker?

Tags: reactjs, border, react-color

Using [React Color](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color) I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to add a border around a [`CirclePicker`](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/blob/bc9a0e1dc5d11b06c511a8e02a95bd85c7129f4b/src/components/circle/Circle.js) color?

The current approach with an attempt to add an `outline` and `border`:

```
<CirclePicker
  colors={colorArray}
  width={'100%'}
  style={{
    outline: '1px solid #ced2d9', // doesn't work
    border: '1px solid #ced2d9', // doesn't work
  }}
  circleSpacing={16}
  onChange={(color: {hex: SetStateAction<string | undefined>}) => {
    onChange(set(color?.hex))
    setPickedColor(color?.hex)
  }}
  value={pickedColor}
/>
```

Research attempt

- [How to set up picker's border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178266/how-to-set-up-pickers-border)
- [customise color picker with out any package in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943694/customise-color-picker-with-out-any-package-in-react)
- [How to Change HTML5 Color Input Inner Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884538/how-to-change-html5-color-input-inner-radius)
- [How can I pick a random border color in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62380984/how-can-i-pick-a-random-border-color-in-react)
- [React Native rounded image with a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086665/react-native-rounded-image-with-a-border)

In React Color's `CirclePicker` is there a way to add a border around a color?